# How to parse the below code in kotlin using retrofit2?

Tags: arrays, json, api, kotlin, retrofit2

```
{
   "message":"successfully",
   "data":[
      {
         "image_url":"http://172.168.1.102:1111/websiteview/assets/images/card_design/1.jpg",
         "id":1,
         "selected":"No"
      },
      {
         "image_url":"http://172.168.1.102:1111/websiteview/assets/images/card_design/2.jpg",
         "id":2,
         "selected":"Yes"
      },
      {
         "image_url":"http://172.168.1.102:1111/websiteview/assets/images/card_design/3.jpg",
         "id":3,
         "selected":"No"
      }
   ],
   "status":1,
   "my_share_url":"http://172.168.1.102:1111/card/62/"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for POJO/Model Class . That would be like this

```
data class Demo(
    val data: List<Data>,
    val message: String,
    val my_share_url: String,
    val status: Int
)

data class Data(
    val id: Int,
    val image_url: String,
    val selected: String
)
```